# How to fetch API resource by ID when ID is not in Nuxt page params

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a RESTful (Django) API which (amongst others) serves a resource called CourseType. CourseType has an ID but it also has a slug.

In my frontend site (built with Nuxt), the URL I'd like to use is something like:-

```
http://example.com/courses/<course slug>/
```

ie. I don't want to use the course ID in the URL.

But the course slugs are not unique in the database. So I can't just fetch the course using its slug as a lookup - I need to look it up using its ID.

What is the best way of doing this from a Nuxt point of view?

I do have access to all of the courses in the Vuex store - as they have been retrieved in a previous API call - so I *could* find the course slug in the store of courses and then use the ID to do the API call for that course. But is that the best way or should I be doing something else?

I'm quite new to Nuxt so this is all pretty challenging for me!